# Proving a function is operation preserving

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, roots-of-unity

I am given the task to prove that f is operation preserving. $f(e^{2πix/n})= [x]_n$ from $G$ $\to$ $\mathbb Z_n$ where $G$ is the group of nth roots of unity under complex multiplication and $\mathbb Z_n$ is the group of integers mod $n$ under modular addition.

I understand that to show a function is operation preserving, I need to show $f(g\cdot h)=f(g)*f(h)$ where "$\cdot$" is the first group's operation and $*$ is the second group's. In my case, "$\cdot$" is complex multiplication and "$*$" is modular addition. The issue I have is that the input of $f$ is not just $x$, but $e^{2πix/n}$, so I am not sure what I'm supposed to replace the $x$ from $[x]_n$ with

Comment: I've taken the liberty of reformatting your question and tweaking the wording for readability. Please ensure that the changes preserve your intended meaning and revert/adjust as necessary. (And welcome to math.se.)

Comment: Remember that an arbitrary element of $G$ is of the form $e^{2 \pi i x / n}$, where $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. To prove this function is operation-preserving, you should take arbitrary $a, b \in G$. Then there are some integers $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a = e^{2 \pi i x / n}$ and $b = e^{2 \pi i y / n}$. Now you can compute $f(a \cdot b)$ and $f(a) + f(b)$ directly and compare.

Comment: If $Z_n$ is a group under modular addition, am I still able to use modular multiplication property?

Answer (score 2):

At issue here is essentially whether $f$ is well-defined in the first place, that is, is independent of the choice $x$ that gives a particular value $e^{2 \pi i x / n}$; more explicitly, this means that for any $x, y$ such that $e^{2 \pi i x / n} = e^{2 \pi i y / n}$ we need to ensure that $[x]_n = [y]_n$. Once we know that $f$ is well-defined, then checking whether it preserves the operation is just a matter of using the definition of $f$, namely, checking that
$$f(e^{2 \pi i x / n} \cdot e^{2 \pi i y / n}) = f(e^{2 \pi i x / n}) +_n f(e^{2 \pi i y / n}) .$$

**Remark** Another way to think about this is as follows: We're checking that the map $q_n : (\Bbb Z, +) \to (\Bbb Z_n, +_n)$, $a \mapsto [a]_n$ is constant on the fibers of the map $\epsilon: (\Bbb Z, +) \to (G, \,\cdot\,)$, $a \mapsto e^{2 \pi i a / n}$. It is, so there is a map $F : G \to \Bbb Z_n$ satisfying $F \circ \epsilon = q_n$, and unwinding definitions we see that the latter statement is just that the induced map $F$ is just the given map $f$. In fact, if we already know that $q_n$ and $\epsilon$ preserve operations, then we can conclude that $f$ does, too.